# Regular Expression in teradata

Tags: teradata

I need to search few patterns from a column using regular expression in `Teradata`.
One of the example is mentioned below:

```sql
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('1-2-3','([0-9] *- *[0-9] *- *[0-9])',1, 1, 'i'),
    '([0-9] *- *[0-9] *- *[0-9])',
    1, 1, 'i'
  ) AS Tmp,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    tmp,
    '(^[0-9])',1,1,'i') || '-' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp,'([0-9]$)',
    1, 1, 'i'
  ) AS final_exp
;
```

In the above expression, I am extracting "1-3" out of a pattern like "1-2-3". Now the patterns can be anything like: 1-2-3-4-5 or 1-2,3 or 1&2-3 or 1-2,3 &4.
Is there any way that I can generalize the search pattern in regular expression like [-,&]* will only search for occurrence of this characters in order, but the characters can be present in any order in the data. 
Few examples mentioned below,need is to fetch all the desired result set using a single pattern serch in expression.

```
Column name           ==>  Result  
abc 1-2+3- 4          ==> 1-4  
def 10,12 & 13        ==> 10-13  
ijk 1,2,3, and 4 lmn  ==> 1-4  
abc1-2 & 3 def        ==> 1-3  
ikl 11 &12 -13        ==> 11-13   
oAy$ 7-8 and 9        ==> 7-9
```

Comment: Can you explan the logic you want to apply and add some example data plus expected result?

Comment: Logic to be followed is to cut out the least and max numbers from the pattern and eliminate the special characters in it, and then separate the two numbers by '-'

Comment: *least* and *max* or *first* and *last*? `abc 3-4+2- 1` -> '3-1? And what if there's no or only a single nimber?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It should be first and last number separated by '-' , but the first and last number should be immediately followed by a specific string(let's say abc). For eg : " abc 1-2 &3,4 def 1-3 " , this should search the first and last digits following the string "abc" and result should be "1-4". With the below logic it can result in 1-3. Incase there is a single digit following the search keyword(let's say) , need to capture the single digits only. Eg : "abc 11 def 1-3" should be "11".

Answer (score 0):

```
RegExp_Substr(col, '(\d+)',1, 1, 'c') || '-' ||
RegExp_Substr(col, '(\d+)(?!.*\d)',1, 1, 'c')

(\d+)  = first number
(\d+)(?!.*\d) = last number (a number not followed by another number)
```

There's also no need for those optional parameters, because it's using the defaults anyway:

```
RegExp_Substr(col, '(\d+)') || '-' ||
RegExp_Substr(col, '(\d+)(?!.*\d)')
```